# Callback help in JNI

Tags: java, java-native-interface

How do i call/write a callback function which is in dll. This callback function is actually called from dll and not jni. How would I code this in java. I need an help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Howtos:

- http://journals.ecs.soton.ac.uk/java/tutorial/native1.1/implementing/method.html
- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CJniJava.aspx